# Deleting line from a string by finding specific part of string PHP

Tags: php, string, line, substr

I need help with working with one String using PHP.

**String Example:**

```
This is line
this is second line
this is third line
xyz next line
this is fifth line
```

How to delete line starts with **"xyz"** without using string function `explode()` with comparing beginning of each row?

All I need is to find "xyz" and delete this row to end. I hope that exist simpler solution like explode with comparing each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `explode()` is banned, dare I suggest using regular expressions?

```
$string = preg_replace('/\nxyz.*/', '', $string);
```

This will match a line beginning with *xyz* and delete up to the next line break.

Comment: genial, really thanks, nicely works.. But if i can ask, how it knows where is new line?

Comment: @user2899587: `\n` matches a newline character. `xyz` matches the literal string `xyz` (`x` followed by `y` followed by `z`). `.*` matches anything except newlines. This demo might help you understand this better: http://regex101.com/r/oU0eQ6

Comment: @user2899587 Amal is correct. Unfortunately, this means it will never match the first line. I can't see an easy way around this without missing either the first or last lines - if this doesn't meet your needs, I'd use `explode()`.

Comment: explode in this case would be very expensive, because i need to delete maybe 20 different rows from 50 rows. And missing first line, is OK.

Comment: i am trying, but its now preg_replace hard to learn with my english. Can you give me example how to delete lines starts with "xyz" and "abc" in one row of preg_replace()?

Comment: @user2899587 `explode()` is surprisingly efficient (if you understand C, have a look at the [source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/419d98b291b4dd36e63f34d72445bd954f3ce3e2/ext/standard/string.c#L1082)), and regexps can be expensive. However if this satisfies your requirements, by all means use it :)

Comment: @user2899587 try `preg_replace('/\n(xyz|abc).*/', '', $string);`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways:

Fast:

- find "\nxyz" with strpos() function and store the position as start
- find find \n after the start position
- get substring usnig substr substr() and store it
- repeat
- cut substrings using `str_replace(substrs_array, '', text)`

Handy:

use Regular Expressions `$text = preg_replace('/^xyz.*$/g', '', $string);`